# HTML / PHP How to show error div element in modal

Tags: php, html, modal-dialog

I have a login modal with an integrated error message but i don't know how to display it.

Error message:

```
<div id="loginErrorMsg" class="alert alert-error hide">Wrong username og password</div>
```

Thanks
Jay

Comment: What specifically do you need help with? Do you have the PHP to create the error? Is it a problem with javascript? What have you tried to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is not PHP, is javascript logic flow that you must do in order to show the error to the user.

```
class="alert alert-error hide"
```

The css class "hide" should hide the error message, then you must remove the "hide" class to display the div, for example with JQuery:

```
$('#loginErrorMsg').removeClass('hide')
```

You can then hide the error message again by re adding the "hide" class. Again for example, with Jquery.

```
$('#loginErrorMsg').addClass('hide')
```

Hopefully now you can see this is a JavaScript problem, not a PHP problem.

Best regards,
Rafael